# Windows 10 JDK doesn't run

Tags: windows-10, installation, jdk

My problem is I can’t install any version of JDK on my computer.
My new computer has windows 10 64bit(It’s  current version is 1611).
I downloaded the setup files however; after I double clicked the file, nothing happens.
Installation never starts. I searched this problem on the Internet but; I couldn’t find anything useful. I haven’t encountered this problem before. In my previous computers JDK installed very well. I’d be glad, if you  help me.
Note: I know my English is not best.

Comment: Have you tried re-downloading the latest jdk executable? And are you able to execute other exe files?

Comment: Check the download is not corrupt (checksum).

Comment: I have rollled back the question, the edit wasn’t necessary, since the original revision made it clear which version was being used.  Additionally,  1611 does not even exist, so it’s not even helpful information.  **The edit should have never been approved.**

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and eventually I solved it next way. All that I was needed to do was turn off `Smart Screen` in windows settings

If you don't familiar with `Smart Screen` You can try to read in google what is it and also I attached screenshot with my settings. Now all is ok

[image]